# Random Enum Truncation in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, enums, grails-orm

I have some custom enums that are referenced during the creation of a domain,

```
package locationEnums

enum HazardType {
    Particulates,
    Chemicals,
    Other
}
```

When the create() function;

```
def create() {
        new Location(
                name: params.name,
                hazardsPresent: params.hazardsPresent,
                hazardTypes: params.hazardTypes as HazardType[],
                exposureArea: params.exposureArea as ExposureArea[],
                exposureLevel: params.exposureLevel as RiskLevel,
                comments: params.comments,
                picture: params.picture.bytes,
                survey: Survey.get(params.survey as int)

        ).save()
```

is executed with the hazard selection as 'Chemical' I get the following error:

```
URI: /location/create
Class: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message: null
Caused by: No enum constant locationEnums.HazardType.C
```

As you can see the selection 'Chemical' is truncated to 'C' and I have no idea why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: might be worth doing println "params are $params" in create function to see if you can spot that HazardType.C in the output. checkout queuekit plugin I used an enum for priorty - the enum sits in src/groovy and works fine in the domain class

Comment: @vahid I have run it in debug and tracked the params all the way through. They are correct until it tries to save then it messes it all up...

Comment: very difficult to comment considering you don't have .C in the save fields try def a = new Location(..)  if (!a.save()) { println "errors ${e.errors}" } to get get more of an idea of what object in the domain class is failing was it working before  ?

Comment: No it was not. If any of the other enum values are selected in the application it continues to truncate them down. The issues with simply changing the enum values to the first letter is they are referenced properly how they are across the entire system.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this method to your `enum` might solve the issue,

```
String getKey() { name() }
```

Btw, what are you getting in `params.hazardTypes`? Or how is your input field in the GSP? I suppose, it is a `<g:select .. multiple="multiple" ...>`.

Comment: It is a custom one `<b:hazardTypeSelect/>`. If that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The way the data was coming in was an array of strings. So prior to the creation I move them from an array of strings to an arraylist of the enum type.